# Tmux does not appear to load .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, tmux

I'm trying to start using tmux and 'fixing' the fact that tmux doesn't load my `.bashrc` on startup. I tried to do all fixes like adding `source ~/.bashrc` to `~/.profile` or creating `~/.bash_profile` and adding to that. Even when I start tmux and run `source ~/.bashrc` nothing changes.

My `.bashrc` has some minor changes to how the directories are shown after the username and of course the colors. When I start tmux, the directories are shown as they would if nothing was altered in `.bashrc` and the color is the same as the text color, which in a normal bash session is not the case.

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/320465/79839

Answer (score 3):

Since you revealed no exact information about your `.bashrc`, I'm going to play a psychic and read it remotely.

There is a condition similar to

```
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|xterm-256color) …
```

and your prompt depends on it. In details it *may be* like

```
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|xterm-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

and then for example

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

If this is the case then there's the culprit: tmux uses `screen`, `tmux` or similar string (such as `tmux-256color`) as `$TERM`. The string your tmux uses does not fulfill the condition in your `.bashrc` for enabling a colored prompt.

While inside Bash inside tmux invoke `echo "$TERM"`. Whatever you get, it should be able to handle colors; so just add it to the condition. Example:

```
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|xterm-256color|screen) …
```

You can learn about the concept of `$TERM` from answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93376/108618).

Comment: Damn, you were spot on. Thanks. I'm sorry for not giving enough details, I just didn't understand what you meant by "what you bashrc looks like"  and certainly didn't know how to get that to you. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[Buried in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360545/tmux-not-colorizing-ps1-prompt#comment1290620_577104), I found there's a cleaner  solution than modifying that part of the .bashrc. If you have a "modern" enough .bashrc, that `case "$TERM"` line will read:

```bash
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

In that case, you can just add this setting to your `.tmux.conf`, without any loss of functionality:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```